# How can I stop ajax.periodicalupdater in my script?

Tags: ajax, prototypejs

I am currently working on a project using mainly php and I needed ajax to relaunch a request periodically. But my knowledge in javascript is nearly 0.

I have recently found that I could use Ajax.PeriodicalUpdate by prototype to do this and it works fine. I use it to look in my php database if a new element has been added and when it is done my script redirects the user to another page. However, once that the user is on this page, Ajax.PeriodicalUpdate is still working and brings the user back to the previous page.

I would like to avoid that. I have found on prototype documentation that I just need to use a stop but I think that I don't use it correctly...

I have 2 php pages:

on Page 1, in the HEAD section I have:

```
var attente= new Ajax.PeriodicalUpdater('attente', 'Page2.php', {
    frequency: 1
});
```

on Page 2
I should insert something like attente.stop(); in the body section, when the condition is fulfilles but it does not work...

Also where should I insert on my page 2

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="prototype.js"></script>
```

in the head section or just before the stop?

Answer (score 1):

Your Page2.php should return something that you can recognize at Page1.php for example:

Page2.php

```
<?php 
if($conditionFulfilled) 
   echo 'Stop' 
else 
   echo 'Continue' 
?>
```

(usually it is done with [json](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) but for your case simple string should do the job)

Then at Page1.php you can have something similar to:

```
var attente = new Ajax.PeriodicalUpdater('attente', 'Page2.php', { 
        frequency: 1,
        method:'get',
        onSuccess: function(transport){
          var response = transport.responseText || "no response text";
          alert("Success! \n\n" + response);
          // compare response with 'Stop' 
          if(response == 'Stop') {
             attente.stop();
          }
        },
        onFailure: function(){ alert('Something went wrong...') }
      });
```

For further info see:

http://www.prototypejs.org/learn/introduction-to-ajax

and

http://www.prototypejs.org/api/ajax/periodicalupdater

And for the part on where to insert prototype.js on Page2.php, the answer is: you might not need need it at (usually it should go under the head section).

Comment: Thank you so much dragan! I am going to try a find a way to adapt the example that you have given me to my script!